# Where and when does the "Delphinum natare doces" proverb originate from?

Tags: history, saying

The first occurrence of "*Delphinum natare doces*" I could find is in Erasmus' *Adagia*, after year 1500.  Due to the nature of this book, the proverb itself must be much older than that.

Where and when does it originate from ?

Comment: NB : My goal is to find a relevant flag or symbol which could be associated to the proverb in order to identify the culture from which it comes, for a children book.

Comment: If you are looking for a Latin quote, is this any use?: 'Faster than asparagus cooks.' *velocius quam asparagi coquuntur.' Lit: 'Faster than Asparagusses are being cooked;' the plural and passive prevent this being read as Faster than asparagus sprouts; metaph. use *coquo.*

Comment: @Hugh Thanks, but actually the constraint is not on being in Latin, but on involving a dolphin.  Therefore for my project I'll just switch to Greek.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *Adagia* of Erasmus was a compilation of Latin and Greek proverbs. This particular proverb (XCVII) is a translation from the Greek, as the entry makes clear. (I am using the 1703 *Opera Omnia* edition available on [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=2cpgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA91&lpg=PA91)):

> **Δέλφῖνα νήχεσθαι διδάσκεις, id est Delphinum natare doces**. In eos competit, qui 
>   monere quempiam conantur in ea re, in qua cum sit ipse exercitatissimus, 
>   nihil eget doctore. Nam delphinus in natando pernicissimi impetus est, ita vt 
>   non modo superet omne natatilium genus velocitate, verumetiam terrestrium 
>   animantium vt autor Aelianus libro xii. Quin et naues transilit seque contento 
>   spiritu teli in morem eiaculatur.

This [online edition](http://jvpoll.home.xs4all.nl/back/Web/erasmusa.htm) includes the following footnote from a German edition, indicating that it is found in the collections of [Zenobius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenobius) (AD 117-138) and [Diogenianus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diogenianus):

> <sup>491</sup> **Δελφῖνα νήχεσθαι διδάσκεις** Dieses Proverb findet sich bei den Paroemiographen: Zenob. 3, 30 = Ald. col. 67-68. Diogen. 4, 33. Suid. δελφῖνα 212 (cf. Adag. 393, n.l. 468). Diogen. 1, 65 (cf. Adag. 398, n.l. 498). Apost. 5, 96. Cf. Zenob. Ald. col. 68: Δελφῖνα νήχεσθαι παιδεύεις.

The very similar adage *piscem natare doces* (XIX) is explicitly attributed by Erasmus to Diogenianus (see [the 1703 edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=2cpgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA853&lpg=PA853)), so this strikes me as plausible.

Given that these Greek sources were compiled so long ago, I do not think it would be easy to trace the phrase further than this.

Comment: Thanks.  As far as I'm concerned, there is no need to trace it further, and anyway it would be off-topic since latin is not relevant anymore.